# Nice representation of byte array and its size

Tags: c++, arrays

How would you represent byte array and its size nicely? I'd like to store (in main memory or within a file) raw byte arrays(unsigned chars) in which first 2/4 bytes will represents its size. But operations on such array does not look well:

```
void func(unsigned char *bytearray)
{
  int size;
  memcpy(&size, bytearray, sizeof(int));
  //rest of operation when we know bytearray size
}
```

How can I avoid that? I think about a simple structure:

```
struct bytearray
{
  int size;
  unsigned char *data;
};

bytearray *b = reinterpret_cast<bytearray*>(new unsigned char[10]);
b->data = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&(b->size) + 1);
```

And I've got an access to a size and data part of bytearray. But it still looks ugly. Could you recommend an another approach?

Comment: Why not `std::vector<unsigned char>`?

Comment: Cause Its not so effective If I would like to store it in a file for example.

Comment: If you want to ask about how to store data in a file, do that. But your question was, I thought, about how to represent it as a C++ type.

Comment: @David Schwartz Thank you. I clarify my question. I don't care or don't know about an underlying storage. It could be a mmaped file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're effectively re-inventing the ["Pascal string"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_%28computer_science%29#Length-prefixed).  However

```
 b->data = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&(b->size) + 1);
```

won't work at all, because the pointer points to itself, and the pointer will get overwritten.

You should be able to use an array with unspecified size for the last element of a structure:

```
struct bytearray
{
  int size;
  unsigned char data[];
};

bytearray *b = reinterpret_cast<bytearray*>(::operator new(sizeof (bytearray) + 10));
b->size = 10;

//...

::operator delete(b);
```

Unlike `std::vector`, this actually stores the size and data together, so you can, for example, write it to a file in one operation.  And memory locality is better.

Still, the fact that `std::vector` is already tested and many useful algorithms are implemented for you makes it very attractive.

Comment: You can't write it to a file in one operation portably.

Comment: Due to int binary representation depended on endianness? Or you have something else on mind?

Comment: @David: The code to do so is portable.  The resulting file is architecture-specific (depends on size and representation of `int`), but there are many applications which only require loading the file back into the same application on the same computer (caches, for example).

Comment: @Dejwi: For example, a compiler might or might not put padding between `size` and `data`. An `int` might be two bytes, four bytes, or some other size.

Comment: I can handle it with #pragma pack(1). It is not so big problem.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you have some overwhelming reason to do otherwise, just do the idiomatic thing and use std::vector<unsigned char>.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `std::vector<unsigned char>` to manage the memory, and write a conversion function to create some `iovec` like structure for you at the time that you need such a thing.

```
iovec make_iovec (std::vector<unsigned char> &v) {
    iovec iv = { &v[0], v.size() };
    return iv;
}
```

Using `iovec`, if you need to write both the length and data in a single system call, you can use the `writev` call to accomplish it.

```
ssize_t write_vector(int fd, std::vector<unsigned char> &v) {
    uint32_t len = htonl(v.size());
    iovec iv[2] = { { &len, sizeof(uint32_t) }, make_iovec(v) };
    return writev(fd, iv, 2);
}
```